# Why did I successfully open libcudart11.2 and still prompt me that I cannot find libcudart10.1

Tags: python, tensorflow, ubuntu-20.04

Here is the complete error message I output：
/home/peach/conda3/envs/wjl/bin/python3.7 /home/peach/pointnet2_python3/part_seg/train.py
2023-07-21 09:06:30.426887: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:53] Successfully opened dynamic library libcudart.so.11.0
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/home/peach/pointnet2_python3/part_seg/train.py", line 27, in 
from log import pointnet2_part_seg
File "/home/peach/pointnet2_python3/part_seg/log/pointnet2_part_seg.py", line 9, in 
from pointnet_util import pointnet_sa_module, pointnet_fp_module
File "/home/peach/pointnet2_python3/utils/pointnet_util.py", line 15, in 
from tf_sampling import farthest_point_sample, gather_point
File "/home/peach/pointnet2_python3/tf_ops/sampling/tf_sampling.py", line 12, in 
sampling_module=tf.load_op_library(os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'tf_sampling_so.so'))
File "/home/peach/conda3/envs/wjl/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/load_library.py", line 58, in load_op_library
lib_handle = py_tf.TF_LoadLibrary(library_filename)
tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.NotFoundError: libcudart.so.10.1: Unable to open shared object file: there is no file or directory available

In addition, the installation environment is py3.7+cuda11.2+cudnn-11.2 corresponding to version+TensorFlow2.5 in ubuntu20.04。Please，thanks，Can only downgrade Cuda？

Train point cloud datasets through TensorFlow

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Could not load dynamic library 'libcudart.so.11.0';](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70967651/could-not-load-dynamic-library-libcudart-so-11-0)

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply, but after multiple attempts, my problem has not been resolved. It may be due to my improper operation. I will try again. Thank you again